# Resources for writing good PHP documentation

Tags: php

I am getting a tool ready to make the source public.  I would like to have it well documented for people who would use it as well as potential contributors.  I am already using some rudimentary docblocks and some line comments for class variables.  Currently I am using doxygen because it integrates into eclipse, but I am not wedded to it.

What I would really like to do is create documentation along the lines of [PHP's PDO classes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) with the class functions documented and examples of use given.  I would prefer the documentation in the code.

What books, tutorials, or code examples would you suggest I look at to give me insight on how to craft great documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[phpDocumentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/)